# ArrayOutOfBoundException when iterating through a data frame in spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data set of called people.json

```
{"name":"Michael"}
{"name":"Andy", "age":30}
{"name":"Justin", "age":19}
```

The following code gives me arrayOutOfBoundsException.

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

  val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder
    .master("local")
    .appName("my-spark-app")
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "config-value")
    .getOrCreate()

  val peopleDF = sparkSession.sparkContext.
    textFile("C:/Users/Desktop/Spark/people.json").
    map(_.split(",")).
    map(attributes => Person(attributes(0),attributes(1).trim.toInt)).
    toDF()

  peopleDF.createOrReplaceTempView("person")

  val teenagersDF = sparkSession.sql("select name, age FROM person")

  teenagersDF.show()
```

Looks like I am trying to work through an empty dataframe. Can anyone tell me why this is empty?

Comment: No attributes(1) in first row. Why don't you create a dataframe directly with `spark.read.json`?

Comment: Thanks for that. I added a number for the first row. First row is {"name":"Michael","age":23} Now I am getting java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""age":23}"

Comment: That's because you are parsing it incorrectly. You need to use `sparkSession.read.json` to read a json file as a dataframe. Your code would work if the data was like `Micheal, 23`.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a valid `json` file, you should use `sqlContext` to read the `json` file into a `dataframe`.

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

  val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder
    .master("local")
    .appName("my-spark-app")
    .config("spark.some.config.option", "config-value")
    .getOrCreate()

  val peopleDF = sparkSession.sqlContext.read.json("C:/Users/Desktop/Spark/people.json")

  peopleDF.createOrReplaceTempView("person")

  val teenagersDF = sparkSession.sql("select name, age FROM person")

  teenagersDF.show()
```

This should work